# Manipulating v-list-item-group model with object instead of list index

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using v-list-item-group to display a list of dynamic items (entities that can be created/deleted), of which can be selected to display more information about the selected item.

Up until this point, I have simply been using the model of v-list-item-group to determine which item has been selected.

```
<template>

<v-list>
  <v-list-item-group v-model="listSelection">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">

    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>

</template>


<script>

export default {

  props: {
    value: Object
  },

  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$store.state.items // Collection of entities from a server
    },
    listSelection: {
      get: function() {
        return this.items.indexOf(this.value)
      },
      set: function(newVal) {
        this.$emit('input', this.items[newVal])
      }
    }
  },

}

</script>
```

This approach works fine with the initial data set, as the first element in the list is the first object in `items`, etc. However, if I add an entity in the middle, or remove something, or simply cause one of the items to shift to a different position in the list, the index to item position becomes invalid. Essentially if the list adds a new element, regardless of its position, its value (when selected in the group) is the next highest unused value. For example:

```
let fruits = ['apple', 'carrot']
```

`<v-list-item>` for apple will have a value 0, and `<v-list-item>` for carrot will have a value 1.

```
fruits.splice(1, 0, "banana")
```

`<v-list-item>` for apple will have a value 0, `<v-list-item>` for banana will have a value 2, and `<v-list-item>` for carrot will have a value 1.

I've done a bunch of playing around with v-model and value in `v-list-item-group`, but have not figured out how to avoid this problem. I would be fine with adding an `@click` on my items, and having the items set a `value`, rather than computing based on the list, but I would like the list selection to be maintained based on the `value`.

As best as i've read, [the documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists) indicates that selection in lists should be handled using a v-list-item-group, but the component doesn't seem to support dynamic lists too well.

Comment: I recommend instead of using hard coded integer values make use of the index(id) that is automatically generated when you are using `v-for`. Hopes this helps you

Answer (score 28):

Upon additional inspection of the documentation, `<v-list-item>` supports a value prop, allowing `<v-list-item-group` to use a dictated value instead of the item index.

So the solution was to simply specify the items id as the value for each item, and then use the id as a means of managing the item group model.

```
<template>

<v-list>
  <v-list-item-group v-model="listSelection">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :value="item.id">

    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>

</template>


<script>

export default {

  props: {
    value: Object
  },

  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$store.state.items; // Collection of entities from a server
    },
    listSelection: {
      get: function() {
        return this.value.id;
      },
      set: function(newVal) {
        this.$emit('input', this.items.find(item => item.id === newVal));
      }
    }
  },

}

</script>
```

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for after spending hours looking through the documentation and similar threads. For some reason, the value prop is listed in the dox for the list-item-group component. This documentation is just hella confusing

Answer (score 0):

There is a better to way to achieve it.

You just need to set the value of `v-list-item` to `:value="item"` should be ok.

See documentation of props `value` for more detail:

The value used when a child of a `v-list-item-group`.

https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props

```html
<template>

<v-list>
  <v-list-item-group v-model="listSelection">
    <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" :value="item">
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>

</template>


<script>

export default {

  props: {
    value: Object
  },

  data() {
    return {
      listSelection: []
    }
  }
  
  computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.$store.state.items; // Collection of entities from a server
    },
  },

}

</script>
```