# Vuetify item-group selected item changes when using firestore data

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuetify.js

I am trying to display several cards based on Firestore docs, I allow the user to select the card and take some actions with that data. But when a firestore document's data changes, and you already have selected a card, it will rearrange the cards and the 'selected card' will now be different.

1.) select card
2.) firestore data changes(updated live)
3.) the card you selected is now replaced with a new card (new index)

[image: firestore docs represented as cards]

If you change the middle doc's rank to -6, the top card will move down, and be the new selected card

```
  online: [{rank: 1, id: 3030303}, {rank: 2, id: 2020202}, {rank: 3, id: 1010101}]
```

I looked at a this stackoverflow question but the answer is not working/outdated (as well as others) [Manipulating v-list-item-group model with object instead of list index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819192/manipulating-v-list-item-group-model-with-object-instead-of-list-index)

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-container fluid>

        <v-list>
          <v-list-item-group v-model="listSelection">
            <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in online" :key="index" :value="item.id">
              {{item}}
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list-item-group>
        </v-list>

    </v-container>
  </div>
  
  </template>
  
  <script>
  import db from "@/components/fbInit";

  export default {

    props: {
      value: {}
    },

    data() {
      return {
        online: [],
        selected: []
      }
    },

    firestore: {
      online: db.collection('item').orderBy('rank', 'asc')
    },

    methods: {
      changeSelected(index) {
        this.selected = index
        this.$emit('change', this.selected);
      },
    },

    computed: {
    items: function() {
      return this.online
    },
    listSelection: {
      // get: function() {  // commented out b/c this line breaks the page
      //   return this.value.id
      // },
      set: function(newVal) {
        this.$emit('input', this.items.find(item => item.id === newVal));
      }
    }
  },
  
  }

  </script>
```

I would like the selection to be bound to the firestore doc.id (i.e. unchanging doc name versus the always changing doc data)
Any help is greatly appreciated